# Where can I find the algorithm behind model.predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction

I would like to implement the code for model.predict (https://keras.io/models/model/) in C++. But I am unable to find the exact logic (equations, formula) used in prediction?

For C++, I implemented the source code here: https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep
but unfortunately could not find the equation behind the predict function. (Frugally deep exports the model as a .json file and does the prediction using the predict function).

Would there be any resources that I could refer to find the equations for model.predict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.predict` implements a forward pass of the model, so there is no direct equation, the computation is inferred from the computation graph of the model.

So in order to implement the same behavior, you have to do a forward pass through the layers of the model, where each layer implements its own computation, so its not a simple recommendation of use equation X, because its a large set of computational formulas that you have to implement, one for each kind of layer.

Comment: Would there be any resources that I could check to do that in C++?

Comment: If I understood it right, I would have to re-implement all the layers (used for training) for prediction as well?

Comment: @MedImage yes, thats correct, assuming that the layer is present at inference time

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the repo, it appears you're looking for [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1302).